# Pipleline wont build and shows access_denied error even after changing policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

ACCESS_DENIED: Service role arn:aws:iam::749760571158:role/codebuild-hu-cb-crm-poc-service-role does not allow AWS CodeBuild to create Amazon CloudWatch Logs log streams for build arn:aws:codebuild:ap-south-1:749760571158:build/hu-moxie-crm-cb:7af26655-bea9-41b8-94c9-38b1c7a68d1e. Error message: User: arn:aws:sts::749760571158:assumed-role/codebuild-hu-cb-crm-poc-service-role/AWSCodeBuild-7af26655-bea9-41b8-94c9-38b1c7a68d1e is not authorized to perform: logs:CreateLogStream on resource: arn:aws:logs:ap-south-1:749760571158:log-group:/aws/codebuild/hu-moxie-crm-cb:log-stream:7af26655-bea9-41b8-94c9-38b1c7a68d1e because no identity-based policy allows the logs:CreateLogStream action

I have set up my pipeline and everything is running, even the website is opening but I am still getting this build error

I gave all the required policy but it still isnt working

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells you what to do.

You need to allow `logs:CreateLogStream` action on the `codebuild-hu-cb-crm-poc-service-role` role.

Attach this policy to the role.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents",
        "logs:DescribeLogStreams"
    ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
    ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: I have already created a new role and added a policy                       {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:ap-south-1:749760571158:log-group:hu-be-cb-cwg",
                "arn:aws:logs:ap-south-1:749760571158:log-group:hu-be-cb-cwg:*"
            ],
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ]
        }
    ]
}               this is my policy

Comment: The log group mentioned in the error and the log group you've added to the policy are different.